# App crashes when pushing a view controler

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

Hey when I push another view Controller i get this in my main.m

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I am using this to push the view controller -

```
-(void)showMore:(UIButton *)sender
{
    MoreViewController *moreViewController = [[MoreViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:moreViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I am sending the message here

```
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showSettings:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Here is my Error -

> 2013-09-25 18:16:03.186 Time Travel[1591:60b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
>   2013-09-25 18:16:05.179 Time Travel[1591:60b] -[NSConcreteValue showSettings:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e5ea70
>   2013-09-25 18:16:05.181 Time Travel[1591:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteValue showSettings:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e5ea70'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2e1e5e8b 0x384e26c7 0x2e1e97b7 0x2e1e80b7 0x2e136e98 0x309a055f 0x309a04fb 0x309a04cb 0x3098c0f3 0x3099ff13 0x3099fbdd 0x3099ac09 0x3096ff59 0x3096e747 0x2e1b0f27 0x2e1b03ef 0x2e1aebdf 0x2e119541 0x2e119323 0x32e492eb 0x309d01e5 0x4cbd5 0x389dbab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

Does it crash on the first line or the second? Add a breakpoint to each and click the continue button to check which one.

If it's the former there might be some illegal code in your alloc/init for MoreViewController.

If it's the latter, maybe there some class/delegate methods (viewDidLoad, etc) are the culprit.

What is the error message during your crash? (Sometimes clicking the resume-play-button in the debugger in Xcode can reveal a bit more after a crash.)

Comment: Here, I added the message above @owenfi

Comment: Are you sending the showSettings: message anywhere in MoreViewController? Looks like it is going to an NSValue instead of its intended destination.

Comment: showSettings is the same as showMore(Sorry, changed the name) @owenfi

Comment: Sure, no problem - but that is getting sent to an instance of NSValue (specifically NSConcreteValue), when it very likely should be passed to the view controller that is currently being displayed. Can you add the line that sends that message?

Comment: the message is above  @owenfi

Comment: Sorry to keep going down the rabbit hole: How is your moreButton instantiated and stored? Is your method definition renamed to showSettings: as well? Which class are all of these (the addTarget, and the showMore:) contained in? I assume it only crashes after you touch the given button?

Comment: Have you initialized a UINavigationController in AppDelegate? what about the showSettings method? does it take any arguments? basically the error is caused when the compiler is unable to identify the showSettings method

Comment: I've found the solution, There was something wrong with the definition of the rootViewController.  After i fixed that everything worked again. Thank you soooo much for helping me through this. @ownfi

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find a method named `showSettings:` in the code you posted. You are pushing your viewController in method named `showMore:` So I think, the code should be like this:

```
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMore:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Please check with this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message saying **showSettings:** method is not found

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteValue **showSettings:**]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e5ea70'
```

And I've notified that you are using **showMore:** as the name of your method
-(void)**showMore:**(UIButton *)sender

maybe just change showMore to showSettings, or vice versa